# MAUI NavigationPage properties

Tags: maui, .net-maui

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage there are quite a few properties that you can use to customize a Page. However, IntelliSense comes back with a much shorter list of available properties.

[image: NavigationPage IntelliSense properties]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug I should report?

Comment: In your screenshot, is NavigationPage a type or an instance?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Accounting.View.BudgetViewPage"
             Title="BudgetViewPage"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
    NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="BBTitle">`

@Jason It's in the very top of my XAML, I don't know if that makes it a type or an instance.

Comment: You’ll notice the docs describe some properties as “attached”.  Those are the ones you see in XAML Intellisense

Comment: Aaaand access the other ones in code. Got it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the properties that are not 'attached' via code, not xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find property for bar color there, you need to define your navigation bar color like this.

The easiest way is through **App.xaml**

CLICK ON THIS TO SEE CODE
[How to change navigationpage bar background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7whCw.png)

Comment: Please include the code as formatted text, rather than an image.